# Google Analytics doesn't show purchases but events

Tags: android, google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking, product

I have a problem with Google Analytics for Android. I'm trying to use Ecommerce Tracking but it doesn't work.
I'm sending an hit and Eclipse shows me in the LogCat

```
Sending hit to service  ...
```

Google Analytics shows me under "Realtime" the event (category, action, label) but under "Conversions" not the purchased product.

```
Product product = new Product()
.setName("myproduct");

tracker
.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
.setCategory(category)
.setAction(action)
.setLabel(label)
.addProduct(product)
.setProductAction(new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE))
.build());
```

And yes, I have activated E-Commerce under the Data View Settings

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for me.

Also note that Conversions includes both Goals and Ecommerce. The Realtime section only shows Goals. For Ecommerce you have to wait a while until the event appears in the main Conversions -> Ecommerce section (about 15 minutes or more).

```
// Logs a purchase event to Google analytics, for ecommerce tracking.
private void logGooglePurchaseEvent(String transactionId, String productId)
{
    // Look up the product's price.
    double price = getProductPrice(productId);
    // Look up the product's currency.
    String currency = getProductPriceCurrency(productId);

    // Set up the product.
    Product product = new Product()
        .setId(productId)
        .setName(productId)
        .setCategory("iap")
        .setPrice(price)
        .setQuantity(1);

    // Set up the purchase action.
    ProductAction productAction = 
        new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE)
            .setTransactionId(transactionId)
            .setTransactionAffiliation("Google Play")
            .setTransactionRevenue(price);

    // Create the builder, which combines the purchase with the product.
    HitBuilders.EventBuilder builder = 
        new HitBuilders.EventBuilder();
    builder.setProductAction(productAction).addProduct(product);
    builder.setCategory("transaction").setAction("purchase");

    // Create the analytics tracker.
    GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(_context);
    Tracker tracker = analytics.newTracker(
        getGoogleAnalyticsPropertyId());

    // Send the event, specifying the currency.
    tracker.set("&cu", currency);
    tracker.send(builder.build());
}
```

Comment: I suppose the main thing to notice is

'ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE)
            .setTransactionId(transactionId)
            .setTransactionAffiliation("Google Play")
            .setTransactionRevenue(price);'